# How do I add a space between the Double Quotes and Colon in the key values of the dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The following is my code:

```
import json


def value_list(sentence):

    word_list = sentence.split(" ")





    total_number_of_words_in_the_sentence = len(word_list)

    value_list = []

    for i in range(0, total_number_of_words_in_the_sentence):


        count1 = word_list.count(word_list[i])


        value_list.append(count1)








    return value_list


def wordlist1(sentence):
    import json

    word_list = sentence.split()







    total_number_of_words_in_the_sentence = len(word_list)

    for i in range(0,total_number_of_words_in_the_sentence):

        word_list[i] = word_list[i]


    return word_list

def word_frequency1(sentence):
    dict1 = dict(zip(wordlist1(sentence), value_list(sentence)))

    dict2 = json.dumps(dict1)

##    from collections import OrderedDict
##    my_dic = OrderedDict(dict1)
##  formatted_dict = {f'{key} : {value}' for key, value in my_dic.items()}

 ##   from collections import OrderedDict

 ##   ordered_dict = OrderedDict(formatted_dict)

##    my_list = list(my_dic)

##    json.dumps(formatted_dict)




    return dict2




print(word_frequency1("John is a businessman and John is a programmer."))
```

The output is:

```
{"John": 2, "is": 2, "a": 2, "businessman": 1, "and": 1, "programmer.": 1}
```

The output that I want is

```
{"John" : 2, "is" : 2, "a" : 2, "businessman" : 1, "and" : 1, "programmer." : 1}
```

How do I get this output?

I have tried a lot but not being able to get the output in this format.

Any solution guys?

i tried replace function , formatting as well as looked up some solutions online but nothing is working.

Comment: Why? It makes no difference to the value

Comment: it does not make any difference to the value but i got to do verification of a dictionary in the following format: s = "The rain is wet here in England, and the rain is cold there in Scotland."
correct_dict = {"the" : 2, "rain" : 2, "is" : 2, "here" : 1, "in" : 2, "england" : 1, "and" : 1, "there" : 1, "scotland" : 1}

assert word_frequency1(s) == correct_dict

Comment: Something to note, your `correct_dict` does not contain `wet` or `cold`, which from a quick glance should be included and which may be why you are having an issue with that comparison.

Comment: You have an answer, but just to add a note. A dict is not json. You don't want to validate whether therre is a space in the dict, because the dict is just a representation of the abstract syntax tree. You want to check whether there is a space in the corresponding json produced when you convert the dict to json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `separators` argument to [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) to get the result you want:

```py
dict2 = json.dumps(dict1, separators=(', ', ' : '))
```

Output:

```
{"John" : 2, "is" : 2, "a" : 2, "businessman" : 1, "and" : 1, "programmer." : 1}
```

Note you need to trim punctuation off your words and convert them to lowercase to get the correct result. Also, you should just use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Finally, if you don't convert to `JSON`, you won't have this issue.